# How to require jQuery Cookie using RequireJS in module definition?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jquery-cookie

I have the following module with a dependency of jQuery Cookie. How do I go about passing in $.cookie or jQuery.cookie into the anonymous function? Right now because I'm not passing in anything it's failing in my console with the following error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'cookie' of undefined`

My code looks like the following:

```
define(['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.min.js'], function($) {

  return function themeSwitcher(initTheme) {
    var body = document.body,
        main = document.querySelector('main'),
        activeTheme = body.classList,
        theme = document.querySelectorAll('.theme-switcher li');

    if ($.cookie('userTheme')) {
      $(body).removeClass(activeTheme[0])
      $(body).addClass($.cookie('userTheme'));
    } else {
      $(body).addClass(initTheme);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < theme.length; i++) {
      theme[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var userTheme = e.target.className;

        if (!$.cookie('userTheme')) {
          $.cookie('userTheme', userTheme, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
          $(body).removeClass(activeTheme[0]);
          $(body).addClass($.cookie('userTheme'));
        } else {
          $.removeCookie('userTheme');
          $.cookie('userTheme', userTheme, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
          $(body).removeClass(activeTheme[0]);
          $(body).addClass($.cookie('userTheme'));
        }

      }, false);  

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: Should I not be passing in anything into the anonymous function for either of the two dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cookie supports AMD from the version `1.4.0+`.
The version `1.3.1` that you are using does not support it.